# redirecting when done with the upload

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, file-upload, blobstore

The following snippet uploads the file to Blobstore :

```
    <%!
       BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
    %>

    <form  action="<%= blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/upload") %>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="myFile"/>
        <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
    </form>
```

After I have uploaded the file I get this type of URL :

```
http://xyz.appspot.com/_ah/upload/AMmfu6bzg8RIpHAQlpT-pLNnuEanbll7R6o5l8DRn-6ZRgCBw-ws-ddXiCnBV6r12zNGPmPJeSkeCoa7Jap-iKHBn-G13y_JVa4N7fj1pewu9GdjDgDSGQg/ALBNUaYAAAAAUBZtgd0ddRLqquuPP8d7GHWOS3BGudTi/
```

But I need to redirect to the *upload page*, after the upload has been done. *Since I don't have access to the action form* , how do I do this ?

Comment: Do you know url of upload page?

Comment: @Igor Artamonov of course yes !

Comment: @Igor Artamonov I didn't understand the argument of `createUploadUrl` earlier. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's exactly what `createUploadUrl` does. You pass the URL that you want to be redirected to, and after the upload has completed, it redirects.